# For loop shell script in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I’m trying to delete pods through Jenkins stage. But for loop not working to delete pods. Any suggestions?

```
           stage(' second') {
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId:"xxx", passwordVariable: 'xxx', usernameVariable: 'xxx')])
                {
                    sh '''
                        xxxx logging into cluster working here <===
                        pods= $(oc -n ns get pods | grep -i pod** | awk {'print $1'}) <=== getting list of pods working fine
                        for pod in "${pods}"
                        do 
                            echo "$pod"
                            oc  -n ns delete $pod;
                        done
                    '''
                }
            }
            
        ## Heading ##
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should remove the double quotes surrounding `"${pods}"`. Something like below.

```
for pod in ${pods}
do 
   echo "$pod"
   oc  -n ns delete $pod;
done
```

Also if your default shell is not `Bash` try setting the `shebang` line at the top of your `sh` block.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: I tried this already no luck. I’m getting command no found

Comment: @wlg What's the exact error?

Comment: + pod1, pod2
/mnt/workspace/job@tmp/durable-48944j88/script.sh: line 3: pod1: command not found.      My requirement is delete the pods. So I did Grep the pods and using for loop on pods listed in grep command.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this space: `pods= $(oc`

You can verify by `echo "${pods}'` right after setting.